# cytoscape.js zoom to fit currently selected nodes

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I wish to zoom the cyjs view to fit (nicely contain)  the currently selected nodes.  nodes could be selected manually, or programmatically.  If only a small network neighborhood has been selected, then the zoom-in would be pretty dramatic.  If distant nodes are in the selection, then the zoom in might not even be noticeable.

```
cy.fit(<padding>)
```

works great to display the entire network within the window.  But try as I may, I cannot find

```
cy.fitSelected()
```

or some functional equivalent.

Suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 10):

It's a oneliner, as `cy.fit()` takes `eles` as its first arg: e.g. `cy.fit( cy.$(':selected'), 50 )` with padding of 50

http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/viewport-manipulation/cy.fit