# Focus/Zoom in on part of the graph or a specific set of nodes or a single node

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web, dagre

I am currently using Cytoscape to create a large graph with 500 nodes. I am using Dagre for the hierarchical layout.
Currently the graph is small on the screen because of number of nodes which makes sense but

Is there a way to focus on a single node once the graph is created. Or can I zoom in on a part of graph?

I have tried using animate filter on dagre but it animates the whole graph and does not focus or zoom in on one node or one part of the graph.

```
    this.cy
        .layout({
            name: "dagre",
            padding: 30,
            animate: true, // whether to transition the node positions
            animateFilter: function( node, i ){         
                if ( node[0]._private.data.type === "student") {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            transform: function( node, pos ){ return pos; },
        })
        .run();
```

Also tried zoom, But I only want to zoom one or set of nodes at the same time

```
cy.zoom({
        level: 1.1, // the zoom level
        //How can I filter the nodes I want?
      });
```

Comment: What you are asking for is called "marquee zoom". https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-view-utilities does it. Maybe you can import this extension. Or you can directly take a look at the source codes. https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-view-utilities/blob/96c057558889f31e7fb8d622139b2c783da90a77/src/view-utilities.js#L367

Comment: @canbax Can you show an example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/cytoscape-call-method
How would I zoom on the main parent when the graph loads. I tried it but doesn't work

Comment: @canbax I am trying to zoom the element whose type is view on the stackblitz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cytoscape.js zoom to fit currently selected nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975862/cytoscape-js-zoom-to-fit-currently-selected-nodes)

Comment: @LearnAspNet getting elements is just easy like `cy.$('.view')` this code will get the elements with class `view`.  What you need is more like what stephan says. If you want to use view-utils it is like https://stackblitz.com/edit/cytoscape-call-method-tyuj8c ctrl+shift DRAG mouse will make a marquee zoom

Comment: @StephanT. canbax Thank you guys, I can get the fit working
https://stackblitz.com/edit/cytoscape-call-method-zyrh7v